# Migration from Windows to Mac: Error on Podfile installation

Tags: macos, firebase, flutter, dart

I just migrated a flutter app made on Windows10, to the Mac, and had problems with the app's execution. I searched the internet for similar errors and found several solutions, but none of them solved my case. I tried to delete the files podfile.lock, Podfile, .symlinks, Flutter.Frameword, Fullet.podspec, pubspec.lock, and after that, the code execution (with flutter run) returned this:

```
Error running pod install
```

I tried to run this line of code:

```
"pod install --repo-update"
```

And I received this:

```
[!] Unable to find a target named 'FirebaseApp' in project 'Runner.xcodeproj', did find 'Runner'.
```

I've tried several things and I don't know what's going on.

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.51.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

My app is connected to Firebase, android, and I'm studying flutterfire with iOS.

Comment: might be you're missing the line project 'Runner.xcodeproj' inside your target

Comment: So, what can I do? Would putting the app in a Git repository be a good idea?

Comment: try the below answer which I have written

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the terminal, navigate to the project, and type `rm ios/Podfile`
2. After that build the project with `flutter build ios`

Comment: The log stated that there is a new version of Flutter Available. And it also showed this:

`Xcode build done. 21.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
/Path/flutter_smart_reply-0.0.2/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterSmartReplyPlugin.swift:3:8: error: no such module 'MLKit'
import MLKit
^
/Paath/flutter_smart_reply-0.0.2/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterSmartReplyPlugin.swift:3:8: error: no such module 'MLKit'
import MLKit`

And finally:

`Encountered error while building for device.`